# Run processes use two CPU in different terminals

Tags: linux, terminal, centos, multiprocessing

I have a complex script (script it's just example, it may be a unzip command and etc. and on the other terminal different command; they are not connected) and two CPU. Can I run two different processes (or commands and etc) on two terminals with different CPU each? (simultaneously) Is that possible? It's possible to specify a particular processor in each terminal for processing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run 2 or more commands even on the same terminal with "taskset"

From the man pages (http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/taskset1.html):
taskset  is  used to set or retrieve the CPU affinity of a running pro-
       cess given its PID **or to launch a new COMMAND with a given  CPU  affin-
       ity**.   CPU affinity is a scheduler property that "bonds" a process to a
       given set of CPUs on the system.  The Linux scheduler  will  honor  the
       given  CPU  affinity  and  the  process will not run on any other CPUs.
       Note that the Linux scheduler also supports natural CPU  affinity:  the
       scheduler attempts to keep processes on the same CPU as long as practi-
       cal for performance reasons.  Therefore, forcing a specific CPU  affin-
       ity is useful only in certain applications.

@eddiem already shared the link (http://xmodulo.com/run-program-process-specific-cpu-cores-linux.html) on how to install taskset and that link also explains how to run it

In short:
$taskset 0x1 tar -xzvf test.tar.gz

That would send the tar command to run on CPU 0

If you want to run several commands/scripts in the same terminal using different CPUs then I think that you just could send them to the background appending "&" at the end e.g.

$taskset 0x1 tar -xzvf test.tar.gz &

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `taskset` program to control the CPU affinity of specific processes.  If you set the affinity for the shell process controlling terminal A to core 0 and terminal B to core 1, any child processes started from A should run on core 0 and B on core 1.

http://xmodulo.com/run-program-process-specific-cpu-cores-linux.html

Comment: What to do if the program (script) is constantly changing PID? As the program uses several scripts.

Comment: As stated, child processes of the parent will inherit its affinity.  If you set the affinity of your shell, the script, and its children, should all run on the same CPU.